# Javascript(script) tag is not available in login.microsoftonline.com domain

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Javascript tag is not loaded in the ad b2c custom page from login.microsoftonline.com domain.
But it loads from tenantname.b2clogin.com domain.

Is it correct behavior?
How to fix it to get it loaded from login.microsoftonline.com domain?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is intended.  JavaScript won't run on login.microsoftonline.com and you should use b2clogin.com.  It's best practice to use b2clogin.com anyway as login.microsoftonline.com will be deprecated.